Is Logic an Image of Mind?
This being a Philosophy site, I presume little wriggle room.
As I read Logic, the really basic things Like True, False, Negation, just these three till now, I feel as if More than any Subject, Logic in this case, I AM ACTUALLY Reading about Mind(Meta-Physical) itself, how it works. Conjuntion and Disjunction I haven't looked at and Honestly Implication and Double Implication Scare Me.
As I was Reading Logic, I remembered a line from Indian Spiritual Text, where Ram Ji says, other than thoughts, there is no other "form" Mind can take. And these Logical Concepts, I feel are so so close to meaning that Mind cannot further divide them into finer more atomic abstract concepts. So in that sense if I look at something like -p or p∧q, I feel as if someone has drawn a picture of Mind itself!
Does looking at Logic and Logical Expressions this way makes sense!
Meta-Physical in the Sense that Mind is distinct from Brain. And when I say Logic, I mean Classical Propositional Logic.
[EDIT]
Hey folks this question got "Close" comment, the Category is "Opinion" based! As far as I know that's what Philosophy is, an Opinion. Is it that we are not welcoming any new opinions here?! Does it have to come from a famous person or does it necessarily have to be "previously known" or "fit a mould"!!!!
The reason behind me interested in this is because I have been tackling the subject of "understanding" for many many years now. I knew something for many years but one day it "clicked"! I became extrememly interested in what happens at that moment. So I was thinking if I could transfer "understanding" directly, rather than transferring "words", it would save a lot of time of my students. And Mind being a very important part of it I was ALWAYS interested in it but happen to really come across Mind during my studies on Logic.
Also as I was studying Logic, I felt, the Universe of Logic is not a flat world divided into True and False, there is some structure to it, dimensions, some Topology(I guess that's what it is called in Math), that is the reason behind the "image" part. I am sorry I do not yet know a more precise formal Mathy way of asking it.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


You speak about the terms “logic” and “mind” as if everybody has the
same understanding and use of these terms like you.
That’s a
questionable assumption. And your explication “Mind(Meta-Physical)”
remains unclear.

Each logic deals with propositions and the concepts of true and
false. The standard logic has the basic operations like negation
“NON-p” and “p AND Q”, which are enough to define other operations
like OR, XOR, IMPLIES.
But more extended and refined logical calculi like
modal-logic introduce further operations like “POSSIBLY”
and “NECESSARILY”. And the latter are also used in human thinking.

There exists even a whole series of different axiomatized logical systems
which do not necessarily relate to the laws of human thinking.


Hence focussing
on the mind in the sense of “how humans think” is a too restricted
view onto logic.

Thanks for the answer, however I respectfully disagree with your last statement. I am of the view that any and all systems, including those of Logic are a "Product" of Mind and regardless of how varied human thinking might be, but simple things like True, False, And, Or, Not are fundamental to Mind and these concepts are used in all systems. So in my opinion, focussing on Mind, rather then being restrictive on the contrary covers all the systems...

@AshishShukla I consider logical calculi to be the product of our rational thinking, of course. But I want to emphasize that several logical calculi are far removed from the rules of our everyday thinking - as it developed in the course of biological evolution.

That is understood sir that there are systems that are non-intuitive but regardless all of them were produced by Mind, so since the source is same, it must work on certain fundamentals that are Universal and are so close to Mind that to call them something else as "Logic" or whatever, it's more appropriate to say "That's Mind for You". For example when I was reading about Law of Excluded Middle, Principle of Bivalence, and Negation, I was feeling as if somebody is describing how My Mind works or should work.

@AshishShukla The fact that the human mind invents a certain logical calculus does not imply that our thinking follows the laws of the this calculus. - You may feel that our standard logic describes how your mind operates. But which argument says that your feeeling is correct? To confirm or to refute this conclusion is the task of neuroscientists and logicians.

Ok our thinking may not follow all the defined types of Logic, but classical logic, doesn't feel invented or unnatural. It feels as it truly describes the natural way of working of Mind.

Other Logics may not be "natural" to the way of working of the mind, but they are within the capacity of Mind only. That non-intuitional way of thinking is like another another dimension to Mind. So what I am trying to ask is, whether Classical or Non-Classical, all those various Types of Logic, it seems, are trying to paint a pitcture of Mind, albeit from a slightly different angle...

The human brain, and by extension, the human mind is prone to fallacies. Evolution selects for brains that are fit to survive, not necessarily for brains that are rational. This led to brains that are heuristic in nature rather than rigorous and rational. Examples of simple heuristics are: If you meet a small animal, try to eat it. If you meet a big animal, run away. If you meet a similar  animal, try to have sex with it. Biology in  a nutshell.
Human brains are more advanced but still rooted in the neural anatomy of our animal ancestors. The development of language enabled humankind to pass on accumulated facts of wisdom to posterity, including self-evident ones as the Sun circles around the Earth , all swans are white, and all taxes are bad.
Now, it is true that sufficiently large neural networks (our brains) can, if necessary with pen and paper, execute algorithms and are therefore (trivially) Turing complete. That means that they can do logic by simulation just as computers can do. But only after intense training and even then we are often held back by flawed intuitions.
Even in this day and age, a large majority of the world population is religious, superstitious and disposed to engage with conspiracy theories.
This necessitates cognitive dissonance at a level that is clearly incongruous with a logical mind . If one spends any time on internet forums then it should become abundantly obvious that the human mind is absurd, manipulative, opportunistic and, dare I say, deeply irrational.
No, logic is not a reflection of the mind.
Of course, I too am an irrational mind, so all this could be wrong.

See the question isn't about Logic, or Image, or Mind, it's about all of them Combined. If mind is prone to Fallacies, so be it, I just want to know How, Why it is Prone to Fallacies?! What Path it takes to reach a wrong conclusion, why it took that path. I am not interested really in discussing merits or pitfalls of Mind, I am interested in Knowing What they Are, WHY THEY ARE!!! Maybe a tall order but I'll have to start someplace and I felt, Logic is a good way to try to understand Mind because...

seldom do you find Subjects that are so Intertwined with your Cognitive Machinery that it's difficult to differentiate which is which. It's like the day I read Principle of Bivalence, i felt as if my mind parted into two, something did happen when I acquired that Knowledge. So for me Principle of Bivalence is as important as knowing what other supporting stuff happened in my mind that helped me understand this topic.

@AshishShukla If you want to understand minds you have to understand how the brain works. My best advice to you is to study neural networks. Our brain is a neural network and since the development of deep learning we have a deeper understanding of how they work. They can learn, they can detect patterns. Large Language Models have shown a Theory of Mind as an emergent pattern. Logic eventually derives from patterns. Even a cat uses logic: IF it is raining THEN the cat will stay indoors. It understands the pattern. It understands implication.
